# How to upgrade database field in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade

I have try to add new column in magento database. but its not working using **mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1 : C:\xampp\htdocs\Surabhi\app\code\local\Surabhi\Employee\sql\employee_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0-0.1.1.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('employee/employee'),//table name 

    'address',      //column name
    'varchar(255) NOT NULL'  //datatype definition
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

**config.xml : C:\xampp\htdocs\Surabhi\app\code\local\Surabhi\Employee\etc\config.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Surabhi_Employee>
      <version>0.1.2</version>
    </Surabhi_Employee>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <employee>
        <class>Surabhi_Employee_Helper</class>
      </employee>
    </helpers>
 <blocks>
   <employee>
  <class>Surabhi_Employee_Block</class>
   </employee>
 </blocks>
 <models>
   <employee>
  <class>Surabhi_Employee_Model</class>
  <resourceModel>employee_mysql4</resourceModel>
   </employee>
   <employee_mysql4>
  <class>Surabhi_Employee_Model_Mysql4</class>
  <entities>    
     <employeedetail>
    <table>employee</table>
     </employeedetail>
        </entities>
   </employee_mysql4>
 </models>
 <resources>
   <employee_setup>
  <setup>
    <module>Surabhi_Employee</module>
  </setup>
  <connection>
    <use>core_setup</use>
  </connection>
   </employee_setup>
   <employee_write>
  <connection>
    <use>core_write</use>
  </connection>
   </employee_write>
   <employee_read>
  <connection>
    <use>core_read</use>
  </connection>
   </employee_read>
 </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
 <routers>
   <employee>
     <use>admin</use>
  <args>
    <module>Surabhi_Employee</module>
    <frontName>admin_employee</frontName>
  </args>
   </employee>
 </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
 <menu>
   <employee module="employee">
  <title>Employee</title>
  <sort_order>100</sort_order>
  <children>
    <employeedetail module="employee">
      <title>Manage Employeedetail</title>
   <sort_order>0</sort_order>
   <action>admin_employee/adminhtml_employeedetail</action>
    </employeedetail>
  </children>
   </employee>
 </menu>
 <acl>
   <resources>
  <all>
    <title>Allow Everything</title>
  </all>
  <admin>
    <children>
   <employee translate="title" module="employee">
     <title>Employee</title>
     <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
     <children>
    <employeedetail translate="title">
   <title>Manage Employeedetail</title>
   <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    </employeedetail>
     </children>
   </employee>
    </children>
  </admin>
   </resources>
 </acl>
 <layout>
   <updates>
  <employee>
    <file>employee.xml</file>
  </employee>
   </updates>
 </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

I have used above code but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in file `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php`

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE { $this->getTable('employee/employee')} ADD address varchar(255) NOT NULL");
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

Comment: not working dude. :(

Comment: It is not working because you have to check core_resources table have your setup version value 0.1.1 change it to 0.1.0 and try it.

Comment: i have check this solution before but not working. :(

Comment: its redirect like  url = about:blank page

Comment: Go to index.php remove comment #int_set('displays_error',1); and then check what error there

Comment: nothing display its redirect to about:blank page.

Comment: Have you used code which i have mentioned because it is working for me.If still you can't able to get it work then update your question with code and file path.

Comment: Hey I have updated my question .

Comment: use `$this->getTable('employee/employeedetail')` instead off `$this->getTable('employee/employee')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39313/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-prashant-valanda).

Comment: What is actual problem let me know

Answer (score 1):

What is the version value of this module in `core_resource` table?

Also try to change the version to 0.1.1 in your xml file and try.

Comment: version value is 0.1.0 in core resource table

Comment: I am already try this with xml

Comment: I am assuming you even tried by renaming the file to 0.1.2